# How to collapse the main AppBar with multiple Tabs in the body

Tags: flutter

I have the following setup in futter as shown in the picture.
The Scaffold->AppBar->TabBarView->
Than multiple tabs and in the first Tab a ListView for the chat.

I would like that the main AppBar is completely collapsing as long the user scrolls up. I am aware of the SliverAppBar in flutter but don't know how that would translate to this use case where I have multiple Tabs. When the user starts navigating to another tab the Appbar should simply show again and if the second Tab has also a ListView it should listen to that ListView.

[image]

Comment: Not clear. Considering you have your tabbar replacing the title, I don't understand how you can collapse the appbar

Comment: The AppBar title holds the TabBar. So the AppBar could collapse when scrolling to gain that area for reading the chat. Does that answer it?

Comment: But your scroll is bottom to top

Comment: yes, correct it is

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I exactly understand the description, but it sounds like what you're looking for is [NestedScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView-class.html).

On the website there is sample code for `SliverAppBar` used with `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: Put the TabBar in the headerSliverBuilder, and in the body put the TabBarView. The docs have sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this sites for your scenario:

https://medium.com/flutter/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-widget-guide-sliverlist-widget-in-5-mins-or-less-d1215c677388

https://androidmonks.com/sliverappbar-flutter/